# Return response of android volley in workmanager

Tags: android, android-volley, android-workmanager

I've been trying to implement android volley with Workmanager for background data upload. No issues at all with implementation, but it's really hard to catch and return response result via Result.success to register.

```
override fun doWork(): Result {


    var volley = VolleySingleTon.getInstance(mContext)
        .syncLocationData(mContext, location, success = Function { collection ->

        ERROR HERE************
           **Need to return the return Result.success()**
           **but i can't return the above**

        }, failure = Function { collection ->

        ERROR HERE************
           **Need to return the return Result.failure()**
          **but i can't return the above**
        })


}
```

Volley request method class

```
fun syncLocationData(
    context: Context,
    location: List<VehicleLocation>, success: Function<RestCollection, Any>, failure: Function<RestCollection, Any>
) {

    var jsonObject: JSONObject? = null
    val jsonString = RestUtil.getGson().toJson(location)

    try {
        jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonString)
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    addToRequestQueue(
        JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            AppConstants.WEB_SERVER.toString + AppConstants.SYNC_LOC_DATA.toString, jsonObject,
            SuccessHandler(context, null, success),
            ErrorHandler(context, null, failure)
        )
    )

}
```

The handler used to gather the result from response

```
class SuccessHandler(
val context: Context,
private val progressBar: ProgressBar?,
private val successCallBack: Function<RestCollection, Any>
 ) : Response.Listener<JSONObject> {


override fun onResponse(json: JSONObject?) {
    if (json != null) {
        progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE

        val response: ApplicationResponse =
            RestUtil.getGson().fromJson(json.toString(), ApplicationResponse::class.java)

        successCallBack.apply(response.collection)
    }
}
```

}

Is there any workaround for this? Thanks!!

Comment: I am having the same question anyone uses volley with workmanager

Comment: You can checkout this article https://medium.com/@oyinloyeayodeji/return-a-response-for-android-volley-when-using-workmanager-e030ecda4dd4

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RequestFuture which is a Volley object. It helps you create a synchronous call in the Worker class

```html
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", null, future, future);
        VolleySingleton.getmInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);

        try {

            JSONObject response = future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // this will block
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            return Result.success();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // exception handling
            return Result.failure();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Result.failure();
            // exception handling
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Result.failure();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can also check out this article for more https://medium.com/@oyinloyeayodeji/return-a-response-for-android-volley-when-using-workmanager-e030ecda4dd4